# What is the syntax of email address with a dot behind it? in DNS zone file, SOA rr

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dns-zone

How i can use a email address with a dot in behind.
For example at bellow, email address is `hostmaster@example.com`, How to use `host.master@example.com` ?

```
example.com.    IN    SOA   ns.example.com. hostmaster.example.com. (...)
```

I can not use `host.master.example.com.` because email called host@master.example.com

Comment: `hostmaster` is the RFC-standard name for the email address associated with DNS records. You should not change it without a very compelling reason.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't (reliably). You can escape the dot (using a \) in the mailbox name, but this isn't always an option. Escaping the dot isn't officially standardized anywhere that I am aware of and although it is widely supported these days there isn't any guarantee that it will be properly parsed by any consumer of that information.

See the following resources:

http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch8/soa.html
email-addr

> Email address of the person responsible for this zone and to which
>   email may be sent to report errors or problems. In the jargon this is
>   called the RNAME field which is why we called it email-addr. The email
>   address of a suitable DNS admin but more commonly the technical
>   contact for the domain. By convention (in RFC 2142) it is suggested
>   that the reserved mailbox hostmaster be used for this purpose but any
>   sensible and stable email address will work. NOTE: Format is
>   mailbox-name.domain.com, for example, hostmaster.example.com (uses a
>   dot not the more normal @ sign, since @ has other uses in the zone
>   file) but mail is sent to hostmaster@example.com. Most commonly ending
>   with a '.' (dot) but if the email address lies within this domain you
>   can just use hostmaster (see also example below). when to use the dot.

https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2142.txt

> In DNS (see [RFC1033], [RFC1034] and [RFC1035]), the Start Of
>   Authority record (SOA RR) has a field for specifying the mailbox name 
>   of the zone's administrator.
>
> This field must be a simple word without metacharacters (such as
>   "%"    or "!" or "::"), and a mail alias should be used on the
>   relevant mail    exchanger hosts to direct zone administration mail to
>   the appropriate    mailbox.
>
> For simplicity and regularity, it is strongly recommended that the 
>   well known mailbox name HOSTMASTER always be used
>   .

Comment: +1. Given that the RFC also says the account should be hostmaster, and that Administrator is a good fallback name, there is no reason to actually use a person's name and thus no need for any coding with a . in it.